# Android Google Maps location without GPS vs location retrieved from LocationManager with network provider

Tags: android, gps, maps, location, locationmanager

It seems that Google Maps are doing something more than just getting the location from the LocationManager since comparing the 2 data (Google Maps vs LocationManager, both GPS off) there is a noticeable difference.
Do you know how Google Maps can be so precise with GPS off?

Comment: My bad... I was not requesting fine location and after reading the docs I noticed that even if the location is determined precise it's obfuscated to become course location. Not it works. Also the new google services api it's better at retrieving the location.

Answer (score 0):

i found an article from google for this topic. It supplies at least some indication how they do it.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation

Comment: That didn't help so much since I'm wondering what kind of algorithms are they using to get such a precise location without GPS. I'm developing an application that need to constantly monitor user's location (not very precise but better than 2000m precision) without turning on the GPS (to be as light as possible to the user's battery).